# Android dialog exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android

I am having this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:347)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:93)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:235)
        at com.problemio.TopicActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(TopicActivity.java:440)
        at com.problemio.TopicActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(TopicActivity.java:1)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        ... 5 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:347)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:93)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:235)
        at com.problemio.TopicActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(TopicActivity.java:440)
        at com.problemio.TopicActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.doInBackground(TopicActivity.java:1)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

With this code:

Dialog dialog;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
 ....

dialog = new Dialog(this);
    Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit_comment);   
    submit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
    {  
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
          dialog.setContentView(R.layout.please_wait);
          dialog.setTitle("Submitting Your Comment");

          TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.please_wait_text);
          text.setText("Please wait while your comment is processed... ");
          dialog.show(); //this will show dialog 

          String c = comment.getText().toString(); 

          if ( c == null || c.length() == 0 )
          {
                try {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    // nothing
                }
          }
          else
          {             
              ...  
          }
       }
    });


    // Go to the database and display a list of problems
sendFeedback( problem_id , recent_topic_id );   
}       

public void sendFeedback(String problem_id , String recent_topic_id) 
{  

    String[] params = new String[] 
            { "url", problem_id , recent_topic_id };

    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(params);        
}       

public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
    {
        String myUrl = theParams[0];
        final String problem_id = theParams[1];
        final String solution_section = theParams[2];

        String charset = "UTF-8";           
        String response = null;

        try 
        {                           
            String query = String.format("problem_id=%s&solution_section=%s", 
                     URLEncoder.encode( problem_id, charset),
                     URLEncoder.encode( solution_section, charset));

            final URL url = new URL( myUrl + "?" + query );

            final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            conn.connect();

            final InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
            int readCount;
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > -1) 
            {
                builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, readCount));
            }

            response = builder.toString();      
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // What should I do here?           
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {       
        if ( result == null )
        {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                // nothing
            }                               
        }
        else
        if ( result.equals("no_suggested_solution_id") || result.equals("no_topic_id" ) )
        {               
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                // nothing
            }                               
        }
        else
        { 
            if ( result.length() == 0 )
            {
                discussion.clear();

                DiscussionMessage message = new DiscussionMessage ( );
                message.setMessage("This section is empty.");

                discussion.add( message );                  
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {   
                    JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);

                    if ( obj != null )
                    {
                        discussion.clear();

                        TextView topic_instructions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topic_instructions);

                    } 
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                     
                }                   
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                     
        }
    }
```

Any idea what I am doing incorrectly with the dialog to have this exception?

Thanks!

Comment: What is written in line 440 ?
and in the exception just return null(doInBackGround()).

Comment: @user1597833 I had changed the code since then and not sure here the line 440 is but it is around the catch statement of the doInBackground I think.

Comment: But it could also be in the onPostExecute() ...sorry I am not sure :( I know it doesn't help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have initiated the dialog in the "onPreExecute()"

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     dialog = new Dialog(YourActivityName.this);
     //your initiation
     dialog.show()
 }
```

And inside the doInBackground() i'd have returned a null if there was an exception thrown.

And try to dismiss the dialog at the beginning of the onPostExecute()

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{       
  dialog.dismiss();
}
```

If that doesn't help then try moving the asynctask to a separate class, and not an inner class of the activity, it usually works for me just fine when I write the asynctask in a different class.

I see that in your code you are calling "sendFeedback()" not inside the onClick method.

You are calling dismiss() on a dialog that has started after the asynctask started running, maybe it could be the problem?

Comment: in your first code snippet, did you mean to have it as onPreExecute?

Comment: actually I had not been using onPreExecute method.  I will try that.

Comment: In your code the dialog can start after the asynctask has started running.

It could be the cause of the problem, move all the dialog initiation to the onPreExecute and it will most likely solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were trying to show a Toast in your `doInBackground()` catch-block, which you cannot do because you are trying to create a UI element on a different Thread.

Simply use a flag to indicate an error occured and move this Toast to `onPostExecute()`:

```
boolean error = false;
protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
{
    // same as before
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // Handle the error gracefully
        error = true;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{       
    if(error) {
        // Show your Toast here, you have access to the UI thread
    }
    // etc
}
```